# Sitecore 8 - Replacing title to data-original-title attribute when adding links on rich text

Tags: hyperlink, sitecore, richtext

I need to replace the title attribute generated when link is added on sitecore rich text. I'm new in sitecore. Any leads on how to do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but it will need custom code. Here is what you'll need to do:

1. Create a class and inherit ItemLinkExpander. Override the expand method. In this method you will add the logic to replace the title attribute.
2. Create a class and inherit LinkParser. Override the GetExpanders method and return a collection that includes your custom ItemLinkExpander from step 1.
3. Create a class and inherit LinkProvider. Override the CreateLinkParser method and return the LinkParser created in step 2.
4. Register LinkProvider from step 3 and make this the default LinkProvider

An example of this can be found [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6232/set-data-attributes-for-links-to-certain-items)